# Detect if a Gtk.TreeNode is expanded

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

Basically I want to know if a given nodes children are visible in a Gtk.NodeView. I've tried tracking it myself however when you click on expand symbol next to a node it goes through a different function than when you click on the node itself.

so here's a basic diagram to try to explain.

-MainNode1
----ChildNode1
----ChildNode2
-MainNode2

so what I want to know is can the user see the child nodes of mainNode1. The problem that I'm running into trying to track this behavior with a bool value on the node itself is there are so many ways the node can be expanded that the bool value might get set to the wrong thing so I'm looking for a better way.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution there's a function called getrowexpanded that I apparently missed when looking for a solution